# Issue with passing paramters to a class method in Python

Tags: python

I have been playing with Python for the past week and I running into a problem with passing 4 parameters to a class method.

**Here is the class method defined within it's class:**

```
class Line:
    locx0 = 0
    locy0 = 0 
    locx1  = 0
    locy1 = 0
    def __init__(self):
        print'<<Line __init__()>>'


    def setLineCoordinates(locx0, locy0, locx1, locy1):
       self.locx0 = locx0
       self.locy0 = locy0
       self.locx1  = locx1
       self.locy1 = locy1



    def getLineCoordinatesX0():
        return self.x0

    def getLineCoordinatesY0():
        return self.y0  

    def getLineCoordinatesX1():
        return self.x1

    def getLineCoordinatesY0():
        return self.y0
```

**Here is where I call the class method:**

```
def LineDepot():
    x0 = None
    x1 = None
    y0 = None
    y1 = None
    line = Line()
    print"Please enter starting and ending coordinates "
    print"If no value is entered, then it will be assumed that the coordinate value is zero "
    x0 = int(input('Enter value for initial x coordiante : '))
    y0 = int(input('Enter value for initial y coordiante : '))
    x1 = int(input('Enter value for end x coordiante :'))
    y1 = int(input('Enter value for end y coordiante :'))

    line.setLineCoordinates(x0, y0, x1, y1)
```

**This is the error I have been getting in the output :**

```
Please make a selection from the following menu...
1.Create a new Line
2.View current lines 
3.View logs
4.Mail line info or logs
5.View summary of line stats
6.Exit this program
Menu Selection:1
<<Line __init__()>>
Please enter starting and ending coordinates 
If no value is entered, then it will be assumed that the coordinate value is zero 
Enter value for initial x coordiante : 1
Enter value for initial y coordiante : 2
Enter value for end x coordiante :3
Enter value for end y coordiante :4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./linear.line.py", line 107, in <module>
    Main()
  File "./linear.line.py", line 15, in Main
    Menu()
  File "./linear.line.py", line 52, in Menu
    LineDepot()
  File "./linear.line.py", line 32, in LineDepot
    line.setLineCoordinates(x0, y0, x1, y1)
TypeError: setLineCoordinates() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)
```

I trying to figure out for the life of me why when I pass 4 arguments, the interpreter is
telling me that I am trying to pass 5.

I have and continue to be in the process of researching the problem.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Formatting note: please indent code snippets and such by 4 spaces. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to make your class inherit from `object`. If you don't, you're using old-style classes, and that's bad.

Comment: Another thing to note: Those functions are instance methods, not classmethods.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing self in your definition

When a class method is called python includes the objects reference as the first function argument

```
def setLineCoordinates(self,x0,y0,x1,y1)
def getLineCoordinatesX0(self):
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add `self` to the class methods' definitions. The first parameter (which by convention is called `self`) contains a reference to the object instance, and it needs to be explicitly written in the definition, whereas it will be implicitly added when the method is called.

```
def setLineCoordinates(self, locx0, locy0, locx1, locy1):
     etc...
```

should work better.

Answer (score 3):

FYI - that is an instance method and not a class method.  There are three method types in python.

- A *class method* is a method that receives a `class` object as the first argument
- A *static method* is a method with absolutely no context
- An *instance method* is a method that receives a instance of a `class` as the first argument

Each of the method types has a different use and purpose.  As others have stated, you are missing the `self` instance argument to your instance methods.  Here's a little example of each of the method types and how they are called for comparison.

```
class C:
   c_class_var = 1
   def __init__(self):
     self.instance_var = 2

   def instance_method(self):
     print
     print 'instance_method called for object', self
     print 'dir()', dir()
     print 'dir(self)', dir(self)

   @staticmethod
   def static_method():
     print
     print 'static_method called, no context exists!'
     print 'dir()', dir()

   @classmethod
   def class_method(cls):
     print
     print 'class_method called for class', cls
     print 'dir()', dir()
     print 'dir(cls)', dir(cls)

class D(C):
   d_class_var = 3

c_obj = C()
c_obj.instance_method()
C.static_method()
C.class_method()

d_obj = D()
d_obj.instance_method()
D.static_method()
D.class_method()
```

and here is the output:

```
instance_method called for object <__main__.C instance at 0x00A706E8>
dir() ['self']
dir(self) ['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'c_class_var', 'class_method', 'instance_method', 'instance_var', 'static_method']

static_method called, no context exists!
dir() []

class_method called for class __main__.C
dir() ['cls']
dir(cls) ['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'c_class_var', 'class_method', 'instance_method', 'static_method']

instance_method called for object <__main__.D instance at 0x00A70710>
dir() ['self']
dir(self) ['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'c_class_var', 'class_method', 'd_class_var', 'instance_method', 'instance_var', 'static_method']

static_method called, no context exists!
dir() []

class_method called for class __main__.D
dir() ['cls']
dir(cls) ['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'c_class_var', 'class_method', 'd_class_var', 'instance_method', 'static_method']
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put self in the method name.

```
class Line():
    def setLineCoordinates(self,locx0, locy0, locx1, locy1):
       self.locx0 = locx0
       self.locy0 = locy0
       self.locx1  = locx1
       self.locy1 = locy1

    def getLineCoordinatesX0(self):
        return self.x0
```

In python the passing of the self variable has to be explicit (it is not implicit like C++).

Answer (score 1):

Your function definition is missing `self

```
def setLineCoordinates(self, locx0, locy0, locx1, locy1):
    self.locx0 = locx0
    ....
```